# How to run GUI from Server with Client

Tags: java, user-interface, server, client

Hello guys i made Battleship GUI on the Server, i can connect with the client
but how can i run the GUI Apllication which is on the server with the client ?

Dont know how to tackle this problem

Comment: You need an application with the GUI on the client's machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client needs to download the GUI Application as a jar file and then run it.

```
    URL website = new URL("http://www.mywebsite.com/gui-application.jar");
    Path path = Paths.get("gui-application.jar");
    try (InputStream in = website.openStream()) {
        Files.copy(in, path, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    }

    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", path.toAbsolutePath().toString());
    Process guiApplication = processBuilder.start();
```

Comment: ah okay and there is no other way around ?

Comment: Please add a specific code example to your question, as it's unclear to me what you have coded. 

Whatever GUI you code on your server will not be visible to the clients because the GUI is running on your server instead of the client. 

All GUIs must be incorporated into the client. Imagine your server is a computer that is always online and connected to the internet at your friend's house. How would you view a GUI on your friend's computer from your home? Only way would be screenshare or remote desktop. This is why everyone needs their own GUI in their client.